# Hiding a div that on the next line

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, responsive

I am using Bootstrap for Auto Layout Columns.

I'd like to hide the `div` that breaks to the next line. I've tried to set a fixed height to the class `row` and then use `@media` queries.

Can you advise a better way ?

```html
<!-- Bootstrap-4 -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Body -->
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm" style="min-width:300px;">1 of 4</div>
    <div class="col-sm" style="min-width:300px;">2 of 4</div>
    <div class="col-sm" style="min-width:300px;">3 of 4</div>
    <div class="col-sm" style="min-width:300px;">4 of 4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: "Better" how? Besides your opinion, how will answers be judged?

Answer (score 1):

> I'd like to hide the div that breaks to the next line.  I tried to set a fixed height to the "row" div...

You're right on track, you just have to set the `overflow` to `hidden` (default value of the `overflow` property is `visible`) to hide *the div that breaks to the next line*. See the snippet below:

```css
.row {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 1.5em;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 620px) {
  .row{
    height: auto;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- Bootstrap-4 -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">


<!-- Body -->
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm" style="min-width:300px;">1 of 4</div>
    <div class="col-sm" style="min-width:300px;">2 of 4</div>
    <div class="col-sm" style="min-width:300px;">3 of 4</div>
    <div class="col-sm" style="min-width:300px;">4 of 4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

More on `overflow` [here](https://www.w3schools.com/csS/css_overflow.asp).

Comment: this however only works if a div is less then 1.5em in height. Otherwise even those divs will be cut.

Comment: Thank you Yong for the quick reply. That is what I am currently doing. I was wondering if there is any better way.

Comment: @tacoshy I was adding to what he tried about using fixed height :) Not assuming it's the best answer for a dynamic scenario.

Comment: @Emiliano No problem, do you have any more specific requirements that you want to add?

Comment: It's for a 4 grid landing page. The height of the grid is almost fixed

Comment: .row {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: XXem; 

}
@media only screen and (max-width: 620px) {
      .row {
      overflow: hidden;
       height: auto;
    } 

}

Comment: I guess I can try in this way and see how it goes. Thank you for the feedback

Comment: @Emiliano do you want it to only apply at certain screen size?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242532/discussion-between-emiliano-and-yong).